# Conditional calculation based on hierarchy level using mxd and ssas 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, hierarchy

I am trying to do some conditional logic based on a hierarchy level.
In my ssas cube I have the following hierarchy defined:

- Team

  - Subteam

    - Employee

I want to create a calculated member "efficiency" which does

```
DIVIDE([Measures].[A], [Measures].[B])
```

But only for the Employee level. For all other levels I need to exclude employees where

`[Measures].[c] = 1`

I'm not sure on how to achieve this and I hope someone can help me.

Thanks ahead!

EDIT My current code works like this. The problem is that the members are not filtered on subteam and team level

```
    case when [Organigram].[Hierarchy].Currentmember.level IS [Organigram].[Hierarchy].[Employee] 
        then DIVIDE([Measures].[a] , [Measures].[b])
        else 
           case when [Measures].[c] = 0
               then DIVIDE([Measures].[a] , [Measures].[b])
               else NULL 
           end
    END,
```

Comment: You should be able to make a start via `IIF` and the function 'Level': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/level-mdx ?
Do you want to add this measure to your cube-script or is is just for an MDX script via a WITH clause ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will supply an edit in my question with my current code. I want to add a measure to my cube (calculations tab in visual studio)

Answer (score 0):

**Following on from the comment by @whytheq**

Create a new measure using `WITH MEMBER` and use the `IIF` test within that. Get something like this working properly first, before you nest a second `IIF` in there to check `[Measures].[c]` too...

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Efficiency] 
AS 'IIF(
   [Organigram].[Hierarchy].Currentmember.level IS [Organigram].[Hierarchy].[Employee], 
   [Measures].[a] / [Measures].[b], 
   NULL
)'
SELECT 
{[Organigram].[NameOfLevel].members} ON ROWS, 
{[Measures].[Efficiency]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [CubeName]
```

Once a simple query is working, gradually add little bits to get more complicated.

You can also check what level you're on with the `.LevelName` and `.LevelDepth` properties. That might make your MDX shorter and more readable, or maybe not.